# How can I get an overview of employee attendance based on a shift plan in Excel?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am working on a report which shows attendance hours in half hour intervalls.
The raw data is an exported CSV file from our shift planning tool Timesquare.

It is formatted as follows:

```
"Date";"Surname";"Name";"Shift";"State";"ID"
"26/06/2023";"Maximoff";"Wanda";"06:00  - 10:00  MARVEL TT";"B";"DE234323"
"26/06/2023";"Stark";"Tony";"06:00  - 11:00  MARVEL TT, 11:30  - 14:30  MARVEL TT";"B";"DE334293"
"26/06/2023";"Barnes";"Bucky";"08:00  - 12:30  MARVEL TT, 13:00  - 16:30  MARVEL TT";"B";"DE948273"
"26/06/2023";"Wayne";"Bruce";"VAC";"B";"DE372839"
"26/06/2023";"Barton";"Clint";"11:00  - 17:00  MARVEL TT";"B";"DE539283"
"26/06/2023";"Napier";"Jack";"VAC";"B";"DE417435"
"26/06/2023";"Pennyworth";"Alfred";"VAC";"B";"DE274288"
"26/06/2023";"Wilson";"Sam";"10:30  - 16:00  MARVEL TT, 16:30  - 19:00  MARVEL TT";"B";"DE412323"
"26/06/2023";"Jones";"Jessica";"06:00  - 10:30  MARVEL TT, 11:00  - 14:30  MARVEL TT";"B";"DE193427"
"26/06/2023";"Cake";"Luke";"08:00  - 13:30  MARVEL, 14:00  - 16:30  MARVEL";"B";"DE411757"
"26/06/2023";"Rand";"Danny";"09:00  - 12:30  MARVEL TT, 13:00  - 17:30  MARVEL TT";"B";"DE398057"
"26/06/2023";"Fury";"Nick";"08:00  - 12:00  Coach, 12:30  - 16:30  Coach";"B";"DE745699"
```

Based on this data, I need an overview of the attendance staffing per half hour intervall in Excel 365.

[The final result should look something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rYNC.png)

First, I cleaned the data via Power Query.

I removed the data for "State" and "ID", since it isn't necessary for the final result.
Then I transformed the "Shift" data, so that I have a single column for "start time", "end time" and "position".

For the first dataset in the example, this would be:
Date: 26/06/2023
Surname: Maximoff
Name: Wanda
Start: 06:00
End: 10:00
Position: MARVEL TT

The position contains, beside the position itself, another information:
is the employee working remote or not.
This is denoted via 'TT' after the position name (which is mostly 'MARVEL', but could be some other position like 'Coach')

To make it easier to work with afterwards, I have created a custom column in Power Query, which states either TRUE or FALSE, if a dataset contains 'TT'.

So far so good.

Since our planning team is not planning lunchbreaks, but rather split the shifts, the data can contain multiple shifts per day.

For instance:

`"26/06/2023";"Stark";"Tony";"06:00  - 11:00  MARVEL TT, 11:30  - 14:30  MARVEL TT";"B";"DE334293"`

This shift would be:
06:00 - 11:00 MARVEL TT (Remote)
11:00 - 11:30 Lunchbreak
11:30 - 14:30 MARVEL TT (Remote)

One problem arises, that I cannot solve on my own.
Let me show it to you on the excel table which results out of the cleaned up data: [PLEASE CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1PLW.png)

My next step would be a calculation of INs and OUTs, employees who are starting their shifts at a given intervall, and those wo end it.

Since the necessity of multiple 'shifts' per day, I am not able to do this properly.
Given the example from above, Tony Stark would take his Lunchbreak at 11:00 and would "clock out".
In reality this is not true, since these breaks are suggested via an algorithm and never actually hit the correct timeframe. Sometimes the employees are taking two 15 minute breaks, sometimes they take their lunchbreak one hour before or after the "planned" spot.

So, what I need would be a further optimisation of the data, which results in "Start" being the first Check-In of the day, and "End" being the last Check-Out.

Again, in the example of Tony Stark, this would be:
Start: 06:00
End: 14:30

Resulting in only one dataset per day and employee.

This would make it possiple for me, to calculate the attendance hours per 30-minute intervall and not be confused by lunchbreaks.

To paint you a larger picture:
we need this report, to evaluate the necessary workstations per day.
It should show us, how many employees are working in the office at a given day and given intervall.

I hope, I was able to clarify the situation.

I am greatful for any help, which can nudge me in the right direction.
And if there is an even better way to obtain the result, I'm all ears. ;)

Comment: I think that using a script (like maybe in VBScript) would be easier for this task: input CSV, output CSV. Would something like that be acceptable?

Comment: You can do it with Power Query: group your data by date, name and surname. Than get the minimum of start time and maximum of end time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this Power query code might do what you require.

Please read the comments and examine the applied steps to understand the algorithm.

Paste the code into the advanced editor, but you will have to edit the `Source=` line to reflect your actual csv file path.

In the code, I have ASSUMEd that you do NOT want to count the remote workers, so there is a line which filters out any lines that contain `TT`. If this is not the case, you can merely delete that step from the UI.

However, if a worker might be TT for one shift and not the other, on the same day, then additional logic will be required.

Also, if you need the column names to be in a 24 hr time format, minor changes will do that.

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\shifts.csv"),[Delimiter=";", Columns=6, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{
        {"Date", type date}, {"Surname", type text}, {"Name", type text}, 
        {"Shift", type text}, {"State", type text}, {"ID", type text}},"en-GB"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"State", "ID"}),

//Remove remote workers
    #"Remove TT" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each not Text.Contains([Shift], "TT")),

//extract start and end times for each worker/date
    #"Start/End Times" = 
        let 
            split = List.Transform(#"Remove TT"[Shift], each Text.SplitAny(_," -,")),
            times = List.Accumulate(split,{},(x, y)=> x & {List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(y, each try Time.From(_) otherwise null))}),
            #"first/last" = List.Transform(times, each {List.First(_), List.Last(_)})
        in 
            #"first/last",

//add Start End columns to the table
//  removing the original Shift column
    #"with Start/End" = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(Table.RemoveColumns(#"Remove TT","Shift")) &
        {List.Transform(#"Start/End Times", each List.First(_))} &
        {List.Transform(#"Start/End Times", each List.Last(_))}, 
        type table[Date=date, Surname=text,Name=text, Shift Start=time, Shift End=time]
    ),

//Remove those who didn't work
// eg VAC, SICK, etc
    #"Remove No Work" = Table.SelectRows(#"with Start/End", each ([Shift Start] <> null)),

//Add custom column = a List of half-hour intervals for each worker/date
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Remove No Work", "Half-Hour List", 
        each List.Times([Shift Start], Duration.TotalHours([Shift End]-[Shift Start])*2, #duration(0,0,30,0))),

//Remove more unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Surname", "Name", "Shift Start", "Shift End"}),

//Expand the half-hour list to new rows
    #"Expanded Half-Hour List" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Half-Hour List"),
    
//Group by date
//Then Pivot each table, aggregating by Count
    #"Group Dates" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Half-Hour List","Date", {
        {"Pivot", (t)=> Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(t, {{"Half-Hour List", type text}}, "en-US"), 
            List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(t, 
            {{"Half-Hour List", type text}}, "en-US")[#"Half-Hour List"]), 
            "Half-Hour List", "Date", List.Count)} 
    }),

//Create list of column names for use further down
    #"All Col Names" = 
        List.Transform(
            List.Distinct(
                List.Sort(#"Expanded Half-Hour List"[#"Half-Hour List"])),
                    each Text.From(_)),


    #"Expanded Pivot" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Group Dates", "Pivot", #"All Col Names"),
    #"Set Data Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Pivot", List.Transform(#"All Col Names", each {_, Int64.Type}))
in
    #"Set Data Types"
```

***Output from your data***
[image]